# How long should it be taking to process the factors of a 12 digit number?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the factors of a very large number (600851475143). I am using C++ and the console seems to keep going for ages. It has reached the number 8462696833 but now has a flashing underscore. I am using an Intel i7 processor if that helps. How long should it take to finish? I am quite new to C++ so here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long n = 600851475143, a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;
    while (c < 600851475143)
    {
        a = n % b;
        if (a == 0)
        {
            cout << b << endl;
        }
        ++b;
        ++c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In under a second: `71*839*1471*6857`

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: It might be helpful if you post you're code here so we can see whether there is room for improvement. I am guessing there will be.

Comment: This is a project euler question I believe, and one of the first ones that demands you think carefully about how you solve it. Naive solutions take too long to wait for, but good algorithms are almost instant.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems like an understandable, on-topic and well-researched question to me.

Comment: @Slavik81 Only one person downvoted. And that was before the edit. The other downvote is the automatic downvote from being closed as NARQ.

Comment: All I was asking is how long should this loop take to execute (hours, days) with a relativity fast processor. I didn't want to know the answer to the problem just how long it would take to execute the program.

Answer (score 3):

You should only need to test up to `775,147` (the square root) to find all the factors. If you have a factor `a`, you can get its counterpart `b` by dividing your original number by `a`.

If you show us your code, we may be able to suggest other optimizations.

Comment: Actually testing to sqr root of the original number is the worst case (prime or semi-prime). Usually much less if we found a factor for the number early, and we only have to tst up to sqr root of the quotient after dividing by the prime factor.

Comment: @nhahtdh But he wants to find all factors, not just the prime ones

Comment: Oh, factors... But still, I think generating the factors from prime factors should be better than testing all factors?

Comment: @nhahtdh I think you're right, but doing that would require a container of some sort which I don't think he's yet familiar with

Comment: Well, I think it doesn't matter much in this case, since 775k is quite small anyway.